# PBI YoY weekly Calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of data.  below and need to return the value for the previous year and the same week so that I can calculate the units and percent difference for each week.  This is  a reduced version of the table.  I have additional columns that I need to do a similar calculation on.

```
FileDate    Units   UnitsLY WeekNum Year    UnitsYOY%
1/22/2019 0:00  3751    2890    4   2019    
1/15/2019 0:00  3518    2625    3   2019    
1/8/2019 0:00   4075    2590    2   2019    
1/1/2019 0:00   4349    2982    1   2019    

WeekNum = WeekNum(PaymentsByWeek[FileDate])
Year = Year(PaymentsByWeek[FileDate])
```

The UnitsLY, WeekNum and Year are calculated fields based on the Filedate.  I would like to calculate the YOY unit change and percent change for each specific week.

```
UnitsLY = IF (
   HASONEVALUE ( 'Calendar'[CalendarYear] )
       && HASONEVALUE ('Calendar'[WeekNumberOfYear] ), CALCULATE(
        Max(PaymentsByWeek[Units]),
       FILTER (
           ALL ( 'Calendar' ),
           'Calendar'[CalendarYear] = VALUES ( 'Calendar'[CalendarYear] )-1
               && 'Calendar'[WeekNumberOfYear] = VALUES ( 'Calendar'[WeekNumberOfYear] )
              )       )   )
PaymentsByWeek),  PaymentsByWeek[Year] =  PaymentsByWeek[Year] -1  &&  'PaymentsByWeek'[WeekNum]=thisweek  ))
```

The formula below gives me a "circular dependency was detected".  I have tried to also put the UnitsLY calculation in the formula but still the same  issue.

UnitsYOY% = DIVIDE(PaymentsByWeek[Units]-[UnitsLY],[UnitsLY])

Finally I have tried this using vars but it returns all zeros values

```
UnitsYOY% = var week= (PaymentsByWeek[WeekNum]) var lastyear =( PaymentsByWeek[Year] -1)  var ly =( CALCULATE(  sum(PaymentsByWeek[Units]) ,
                    FILTER('PaymentsByWeek'
                    ,'PaymentsByWeek'[WeekNum] =week && PaymentsByWeek[year]= lastyear )))   Return Divide(PaymentsByWeek[Units]-ly ,ly)
```

How do I calculate the unit and percent change between specific weeks?

Comment: The last line in UnitsLY is a paste error and should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the DAX in-built time intelligence fucntions?

```
CALCULATE(
          DIVIDE(PaymentsByWeek[Units]-[UnitsLY],[UnitsLY]),
          PARALLELPERIOD(PaymentsByWeek[FileDate],-1,year)
         )
```

Ah, got it. The crux of the circular reference problem is you have reference to [Units] in the formula for [UnitsLY] calc. column. Maybe this would solve the problem:

(1) Remove the [UnitsLY] calc. column and instead use a measure - something like this - I'm assuming here the Units column contains the data for "all the years":
 `CALCULATE(SUM(PaymentsByWeek[Units]),FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),'Calendar'[WeekNum] = MIN('Calendar'[WeekNum]) -1 ))`

(2) Use another measure to calculate the percentage change, i.e., use the above measure in the DIVIDE function.

Alternatively, you can make do with 1 measure if you don't want to display UnitsLY anywhere.

Comment: Looking for week comparison.  PARALLELPERIOD does not support weeks.

Comment: Not sure this is it. The table has several years of weekly data.  This will calculate the sum of unites for all weeks less that a given week number.  If I add  Calendar[calendaryear] -1 it will be the YearToDate sum of units for the previous year ( LY Units).  What I am looking for is   =  (week 4 of 2019 units)  - (Week 4 of 2018 units) = YOY for this week

Comment: so I think I need this     YOYChange = 
         CALCULATE( Min(PaymentsByWeek[Units])  -  calculate( Min(PaymentsByWeek[Units]),
 FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),
  'Calendar'[CalendarYear]= Min('Calendar'[CalendarYear])-1 && 'Calendar'[WeekNumberOfYear] = Min('Calendar'[WeekNumberOfYear]) 
)) )    but this returns the  Circular dependency

Comment: @DanMcGivney, is it possible for you to share some sample data, preferably in a pbix? You may want to remove any sensitive info before you share it here.

Comment: So I think the rules are :  If I am acting on a row in the data table that is from the original data source.  i.e. Query ="Select A, B"  New Column= b + c.  You are good.  If you are looking up a value across the depth of the table you must use a measure.  i.e New Column= Some value from a previous period in the data i.e. LastYear) is a measure even if it is a single row lookup

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.
I was creating columns which gives me the dependency error.  I have created all 3 fields as measure and they work correctly.

```
PmtsLY = calculate( MIn(PaymentsByWeek[Pmts]),
FILTER(ALL('PaymentsByWeek'),
    'PaymentsByWeek'[Year]= Min('PaymentsByWeek'[Year])-1 && 'PaymentsByWeek'[WeekNum] = Min('PaymentsByWeek'[WeekNum]) ))  

PmtsYOY = calculate( Min(PaymentsByWeek[Pmts]) - PaymentsByWeek[PmtsLY] )


PmtsYOY% = calculate( DIVIDE(  (Min(PaymentsByWeek[Pmts]) - PaymentsByWeek[PmtsLY]) ,  PaymentsByWeek[PmtsLY],0)*100  )

PmtsYOY = calculate( Min(PaymentsByWeek[Pmts]) - PaymentsByWeek[PmtsLY] )
```